# Replace column in dataframe based on condition for unknow length of arguments

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

I want to get a new dataframe with a new column name "V6" which is based on conditions which I want to pass through a function:

```
testDF <- createFactor(df,
                    'V6',
                    c('V1>V2', 'V3>V5', 'V2<V5'),
                    c('low', 'medium', 'high'))
```

This is my try so far:

```
createFactor <- function(df, column, equation, factors){
    eq <- equation
    fa <- factors
    df[column] <- ifelse(eval(parse(text=eq[1]), df), fa[1],
                  ifelse(eval(parse(text=eq[2]), df), fa[2],
                  ifelse(eval(parse(text=eq[3]), df), fa[3], 'NULL')))
  return(df)
}
```

I know that I can nest the ifelse() and get the output I want but how can I nest if I don't know the number of arguments. What if I want to pass ten conditions? How can I build a funtion like that. The conditions can exclude each other.
Is there a simple solution to this which is effienct also? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passing code as strings is a bad idea. One option: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(V6 = case_when(V1 > V2 ~ 'low', V3 > V5 ~ 'medium', V2 < V5 ~ 'high'))`

Comment: It seems that the conditions are not mutually exclusive though

Comment: @ed_sans Yes but for this example it is not so important.